# How to save data from actors on system shutdown

Tags: scala, akka

For example I have following actors: `Player` and `GameRoom`.

`GameRoom` holds players with scores. When user left(terminates), we save player score in database:

```
  class Player extends Actor {
        ...
  }


  object GameRoom {
    case object Join
  }

  class GameRoom(database:ActorRef) extends Actor {

    type Score = Int

    var players: Map[ActorRef, Score] = Map.empty

    def receive: Receive = {
      case GameRoom.Join =>
        context.watch(sender())
        players = players + (sender() -> 100)
      case Terminated(player) =>
        players = players - player
        database ! SavePlayerScore(...)
    }

  }
```

But what if I want to kill jvm process (`SIGTERM`)? In that case i have no way to save all users score to database on shutdown.

Any hints how to implement needed behaviour?

Comment: Did you consider that your approach might be totally wrong? How about making `GameRoom` a persistent actor and saving information about player and score into persistent data store as a series of events? It could be made fault tolerant enough to deal with situations such as application crash.

Comment: agreed with @BranislavLazic if you try to save the state on shutdown, how can you be sure the database subsystem will still be up? what if that part failed? therefore, better persist events as they arrive.

Comment: Thanks, i will think about it. I need to investigate akka-persistense first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a shutdown hook that will terminate your ActorSystem (using [ActorSystem#terminate()](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#terminate():scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.Terminated])) on application shutdown.

That will trigger an ordered termination of the Actors hierarchy, and in turn result in your `GameRoom` to receive the `Terminated` for the `players`.

Here is a small code snippet to install that shutdown hook:

```
   Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(
     new Thread("shutdown-hook") {
       override def run() {
         // This obviously needs to 
         try{
           Await.ready(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
         }catch{
           case _ : InterruptedException => // Termination was interrupted
           case _ : Throwable => // Exception thrown by actor system termination
         }}
     })}
```

One important thing to notice here is: **once the code in the Shutdown Hook is completed, the JVM will shutdown** (killing all threads even if they are not done), so if you have any other cleanup to do, add it to the shutdown hook.

**EDIT 1**: The JVM will terminate even if the `Await.ready` threw an Exception. This means that, some of your state might have not been saved or something. You might want to handle those exception then and there because, again, once the `run()` method is complete, the JVM will die.

Comment: What does mean "ordered termination of the Actors hierarchy"? Why `GameRoom ` or database actor not dies before Players? - I think it's a main problem.

Comment: If GameRoom is responsible for saving information for all players, then it probably be their parent (GameRoom actor should be responsible to create Player actors). By doing that you ensure that 1) players are terminated before GameRoom and 2) you don't need to explicitly watch() player actors.